# Help with proof by induction of inequality

Tags: inequality, induction

I am studying for an exam and going through various earlier tutorial sheet questions. For the question below, I have tried and just can't figure out how to prove that $x$<sub>n</sub>$ $ < $ 3$ by mathematical induction. Does anyone know how to prove this?

---

The question is:

> Let $x$<sub>1</sub> = 1, and for each $n \in  \mathbb{N}$ let $x$<sub>n+1</sub> = $\frac{2}{3}x$<sub>n</sub>$ $ + $ 1$. Then $x$<sub>n</sub>$ $ < $ 3$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: If $x_n<3$, then what can you say about $\frac{2}{3}x_n+1$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint : For the inductive step, you have

$$\begin{align}x_{n + 1} &= \frac{2}{3}x_n + 1\\&<\frac{2}{3}(3) + 1\\&=  3\end{align}$$

Comment: A bit more than a hint, I'd say.

Comment: I tried - It probably can't get any more brief than this ;)